# Foundation BlockGrid + jQuery Sortable breaking line

Tags: jquery, html, zurb-foundation, jquery-ui-sortable, zurb-foundation-6

Using the blockgrid when you drag the element, the last element in line out the list.

Can someone help me?

```
$('.imageList').sortable({
  placeholder: 'placeholder',
  forcePlaceholderSize: true,
  opacity: 0.5
}).disableSelection();
```

http://codepen.io/fabiovaz/pen/PZmwQY